# Need 3 digits in column in a CSV-file

Tags: powershell

I have a script that extracts data from an XML file and put this into an CSV file with 2 columns.
The file looks like this:

```
Name, Count
1,34
3,55
15,66
103,99
etc.
```

So far so good...

My problem is that the program that reads the CSV-file always expect 3 digits in the column "Name".

So the CSV-file need to look like this:

```
Name, Count
001,34
003,55
015,66
103,99
etc.
```

How can I do this formatting using "Export-CSV"?

Please help I'm stuck here..

Comment: Please always add the code you already have for your problem! Possible duplicate of [Format variable as 4 digits with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912486/format-variable-as-4-digits-with-leading-zeroes)

Comment: Without seeing the code I would guess you just call [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to apply the changes to the csv file.

Read/Import to a variable, change name, Export-Csv variable

```
$Csv = Import-Csv .\Sample.csv
$Csv | ForEach-Object{ $_.Name = $_.Name.PadLeft(3,'0') }
$Csv | Export-Csv .\NewSample.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Do the same ***on the fly*** with a calculated property reusing the same header/property name.

```
Import-Csv .\Sample.csv | 
  Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_.Name.PadLeft(3,'0')}},Count|
    Export-Csv .\NewSample2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the -f ( format ) operator with variable

i.e.

```
[int] $int = 25;

"{0:D3}" -f $int
```

Here 3 is a number of digits and Output will be :

> 025